# XSLT got the exception in logic apps

Tags: azure, biztalk, azure-logic-apps

When I use the XSLT to transform XML source file then got the below exception in Logic APP. This below URL is avail in the XSLT file.

How to resolve this issue in logic apps?

XSD schema is valid and working fine. At TransformXML place got this issue.

[image: Logic app]

> "Code": "InvalidXsltContent",   "Message": "An error occurred while
>   processing map. 'Cannot find a script or an extension object
>   associated with namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS0'.'",

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems the logic app can't find the external assembly from the integration account. So could you please check if you have upload the assembly to your integration account ? You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-maps#add-referenced-assemblies) to know how to upload the assembly.

By the way, it seems you want to use custom extension in your xslt map. Here I provide two links for your reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/technical-reference/custom-extension-xml-grid-property?redirectedfrom=MSDN
2. https://blog.vertica.dk/2013/03/20/using-custom-xslt-in-biztalk/